# Google Clasroom Python API Use batch request and get the request back

Tags: python, batch-processing, google-classroom

I am new to google classroom api, just started a few days ago. I want to use batch request to make the code faster. My problem is that I don't know how to get the data back from the batch. I tried printing it in the console, but it returned null.

```
def get_all_courses(service):
    nextpageToken = ""
    list_id = []
    while nextpageToken is not None:

        result = service.courses().list(
            pageSize=500,
            pageToken=nextpageToken,
            fields="nextPageToken,courses(id)"
        )
        result = result.execute()
        lista_curs = result.get("courses")
        for curs in lista_curs:
            list_id.append(curs.get('id'))
        nextpageToken = result.get("nextPageToken")
    print("Ther are :" + str(len(list_id)))
    return list_id
```

This is the normal usual code. How can I pass the request to a batch and get the results back?

```
    batch1 = service.new_batch_http_request()
    result = service.courses().list(
        pageSize=500,
        pageToken=nextpageToken,
        fields="nextPageToken,courses(id)"
    )
    batch1.add(result)
    batch1.execute()# how do I get back the result? do I have to call result.execute() again?
```

This is the code from the docs: https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch

```
course_id = '123456'
student_emails = ['alice@example.edu', 'bob@example.edu']
def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print 'Error adding user "{0}" to the course course: {1}'.format(
            request_id, exception)
    else:
        print 'User "{0}" added as a student to the course.'.format(
            response.get('profile').get('name').get('fullName'))
batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
for student_email in student_emails:
    student = {
        'userId': student_email
    }
    request = service.courses().students().create(courseId=course_id,
                                                  body=student)
    batch.add(request, request_id=student_email)
batch.execute(http=http) # what is http? what can I pass there? what kind of object is that?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting `batch1.execute()` in a variable, and printing it?

Comment: ceva = batch1.execute()
        print(ceva)  gives me None

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `execute(http=http)` is, as documented [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.BatchHttpRequest-class.html) the serialized httprequest. What about the fields form the response in the callback function? Can they return the information you need?

Comment: Hi, no problem.There are very few people answering to google classroom tag. So thank you :). What do you mean by serialized httprequest? In the docs the line is like this `batch.execute(http=http)` but http is never defined in the code.

Comment: `http` is just the http object from the [httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2) library used by the API. It's being automatically loaded when you import it so there is no need to define it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a response from this? How have you handled the next page tokens and added them to the batch call?

```
def makeRequestWithExponentialBackoff(analytics):
    for n in range(0, 5):
        try:
            response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                    courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
            print(response.get("studentSubmissions", []))
            return assignments.extend(response.get("nextPageToken", []))

        except:
            time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.random())
            continue
    print("There has been an error, the request never succeeded.")


def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print('Error getting assignments "{0}" for course: "{1}"'.format(request_id, exception))
        makeRequestWithExponentialBackoff(request_id)
    else:
        assignments.extend(response.get("studentSubmissions", []))
        nextPageToken = response.get("nextPageToken", None)
        if nextPageToken:
            iftoken(nextPageToken, request_id)
        else:
            pass


for k, v in filtered.iterrows():
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        submit = batch.execute(http=http)
        batch_count += 1
        print(batch_count)
        time.sleep(30)
        batch_array.append({'batchSent {}'.format(v['id'])})
        batch = None
        batch = service_two.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count = 1
    elif count % 1000 != 0 and batch == None:
        batch = service_two.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count += 1
    else:
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count += 1
```

where filtered is a dataframe of classroom Ids. However got an issue with the nextpagetokens and how to add these to the dataframe?